Como puedo ingresar a smss usando las credenciales de windows
les doy el contexto.
Estaba tratando de iniciar sesión a mi SQL server, pero el problema radica que estoy en mi computadora de desarrollo y yo quiero iniciar sesión en mi servidor. Pero no quiero instalar SSMS desde mi servidor ya que este cuenta con muy pocos recursos, además de que para yo poder iniciar sesión necesito el usuario y la contraseña de windows.
Ya también abri los puertos, active las reglas del firewall, me permite conectarme a SQL server, solo que me rebota por la autenticación, que son el usuario y la contraseña de windows.
Ya investigué en todas partes incluyendo documentación, tutoriales, etc. pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, alguien de casualidad que sepa como iniciar sesión sin tener que activar la autenticación de SQL, solo por el usuario y la contraseña de windows?
Gracias

Pues necesitas un "cliente" para conectarte, SSMS es lo habitual, podrías usar Azure Data Studio que es un poco más liviano. Cada uno de estos clientes permiten elegir la forma de conexión, integrada (login del AD) o credenciales de SQL, obviamente el servidor es el que termina estableciendo la mecanica de login
